# Does progress in S.T.A.R. Labs missions count towards trophy completion?

Tags: achievements, injustice-gods-among-us

There are several trophies in *Injustice* which require you to essentially perform a checklist of things with each character and/or stage. Examples are:

- **Superhuman** - Perform every character's supermove
- **Around the World** - Knock opponent through all transitions across all levels
- **Metahuman** - Perform every special move of every character

The S.T.A.R. Labs missions are preselected scenarios (similar to *Mortal Kombat 9*'s Tower challenges) in which you have to win under certain conditions. For example, in the first fight, I have to use most of Superman's special moves in order to pass the mission.

Seeing as I've now done several of Superman's special moves, does that progress count towards the **Metahuman** trophy? Will progress towards other things, like level transitions/interactions, supermoves, etc. made in the S.T.A.R. Labs missions count towards these trophies or not?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this page:http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/injustice-gods-among-us/195572-injustice-gods-among-us-road-map-trophy-guide.html

They can be done in practice mode, so that leads me to believe star labs will count as well. I have the Wii U version, so I dont have achievements/trophies, but from my understanding of that site, it seems as long as you do them at some point, in any mode, you will get the trophies.

Also, just from the description, usually it will tell you if you have to be in a certain mode, like online only achievements do.